# How to use a regex in Java to manipulate a string

Tags: java

```java
String s = "My cake should have ( sixteen | sixten | six teen ) candles, I love and ( should be | would be ) puff them."
```

#### Final changed string

```
My cake should have <div><p id="1">sixteen</p><p  id="2">sixten</p><p  id="3">six teen</p></div>  candles, I love and <div><p  id="1">should be</p><p  id="2"> would be</p> puff them
```

I have tried using this:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\|)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the input string. It would be a lot easier if the first and last | could be replaced with another symbol. Currently it's hard to know that `six teen |` is the last choice, and that `| candles, I love and |` is not just another choice

Comment: I also think the same way it will be easier.

Comment: I'd go further: right now it's impossible to tell those apart unless you somehow restrict replacements to one word (which doesn't seem to be the case) or only letters or in some other way. They way you've defined it right now this example contains only one replacement with 6 options.

Comment: this may not be the case for all cases of your string, but you can check for delimiters that arent supposed to be there. ie `candles, I love and` is the next part of the sentence and has a , string that would logically not be part of the tokens that are your options. Same for `puff them.` which has ".". May also look into identifying which tokens are the start and end of the string. (using split() gives string array, so front and end of string can be identified, then you can process each string)

Comment: @Robin what if I change the first and last ```|``` with paranthesis

Comment: @Beginner: that would make it much easier (i.e. possible). That's why they initially asked if you have control over the input string.

Comment: Yes i have the control on the input

Comment: Are you trying to replace every `(` with `<div><p>`, every `|` with `</p><p>` and every `)` with `</p></div>`? Because I don't think you need anything other than `replace()` for that. `s.replace("(","<div><p>").replace("|","</p><p>").replace(")","</p></div>");`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

class Program
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "My cake should have ( sixteen | sixten | six teen ) candles, I love and ( should be | would be ) puff them.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()|]*\\|[^()]*)\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer changed = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()){
            String temp = "<div>";
            String[] items = matcher.group(1).trim().split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
            for (int i = 1; i<=items.length; i++) {
                temp += "<p id=\"" + i + "\">" + items[i-1] + "</p>";
            }
            matcher.appendReplacement(changed, temp+"</div>");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(changed);
        System.out.println(changed.toString());
    }
}
```

See [Java proof](https://tio.run/##VVCxbtswEJ2lrzhoIq2EhWdbGQp0yBAgSLtZLsBItESHIgmSsh3U/nb3SElBu@hOx/fe3XtHfuKPx/bjfpeDNS7AEQdsDFIxJzpxYatNnjeKew@vznSOD/mfPLPju5IN@MADlpORLQxcaiA/g5O62@2Bu85TCL0zZz9pKq479uPSCBuk0XmGMtkEBw8VFC@f0PAPAb43o2qh5ycBBLy8BCE0XKdubiDNKBJ0q4R/gGdQBvH4GzmTwrtA8HlpKdjxcMCLxMCKDe5@5SEIp8HOtYJ5whozWKkEKeqakN1vQq/7VV1fY7df0bqmBY0CLzw0vXDofKrVIsXmCfEJN5n8jtsR1PQYg2gRrMUZ/n0iCXzucTOQWYEdpG4JpTGrJawgBhvz2rby9JScZF@pS3yMYS70zpnRkjVlCBgIZd4qGaIvHw3FMlnJDsYBkTqARPZ6A3JbJS2mhO5Cj4OypJDOyNIBZbzAgmyruiigRF4JRV08pT4yd/JxvY/D7Tc7n3mLn@U0bq3Q7ZuwijdiEDqQOZqH5LBEXjKY7ovM/4m/uFQLY0r50yOPmTEwi2kEpZdnFswUEAaJyFt@u9//Ag).

**Results**: `My cake should have <div><p id="1">sixteen</p><p id="2">sixten</p><p id="3">six teen</p></div> candles, I love and <div><p id="1">should be</p><p id="2">would be</p></div> puff them.`

**Regex used**

```java
\(([^()|]*\|[^()]*)\)
```

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()|]*                  any character except: '(', ')', '|' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

**In short**: Match parens with pipes, take the content with no parens and split with pipes, trim,  combine into one string with loop. `StringBuffer` and `matcher.appendReplacement` do the magic with string manipulation during replacing.