# How to use regex in java to manipulate the string

Tags: java, regex

```java
String s = "My cake should have ( sixteen | sixten | six teen ) candles, I love and ( should be | would be ) puff them."
```

final changed string

```
My cake should have <div><p id="1">sixteen</p><p  id="2">sixten</p><p  id="3">six teen</p></div>  candles, I love and <div><p  id="1">should be</p><p  id="2"> would be</p> puff them
```

What i had tried is using this

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: why did you delete the previous question which this is a copy of?

Comment: you can extract content within `(` `)` and create `div` and `p` tags  by iterating substrings in parenthesis

Comment: Isn't this almost the same Question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816052/how-to-use-regex-in-java-to-manipulate-the-string)? Perhaps you should read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Beginnger, please consider  undeleting the previous post. Please remove this one. You would have got an answer quicker if you used the right tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match strings between parentheses and then split the texts inside with a pipe and build the replacement dynamically using `Matcher.appendReplacement`:

```java
String s = "My cake should have ( sixteen | sixten | six teen ) candles, I love and ( should be | would be ) puff them.";
String rx = "\\(([^()]*)\\)";
        
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String add = "";
    String[] items = m.group(1).split("\\|");
    for (int i=1; i<=items.length; i++) {
        add += "<p id=\"" + i + "\">" + items[i-1].trim() + "</p>";
    }
    m.appendReplacement(result, "<div>"+add+"</div>");
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/D536b2). Output:

```java
My cake should have <div><p id="1">sixteen</p><p id="2">sixten</p><p id="3">six teen</p></div> candles, I love and <div><p id="1">should be</p><p id="2">would be</p></div> puff them.
```